# Don't load the image until user scroll to there , possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I don't want the image to be downloaded from server , until user scroll to there , which event should I capture ?

And how ?

Comment: Have you looked at LazyLoad?http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this plugin (Lazy Load) in a project and it works pretty fine.

- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

And here's how, the trick is to put a blank placeholder image, and add a data information with the real image path

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480">
```

then in your code do:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to use native lazy loading with the [`loading`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading) attribute on the `img` tag.

```html
<!-- somewhere in the bottom of your page: -->
<img loading="lazy" src="/your-image.png"/>
```

[Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr) may be an issue if you're trying to support t-rex browsers or designer devices.

#shots-fired